# Property inheriting class

Tags: swift

Forgive me if the title is confusing or it's stupid but am little confused on this

```
var logInUser : User!
```

This is the code `logInUser` is a property and `User` is model class now what's confusing to me is that is it a property inheriting a model class or is it something else and why we are force unwrapping it?
Now through this `LogInUser` we can access all properties of `User` model class

Comment: Read [The Swift Programming Guide: The Basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html).  About 3/4 of the way down the page you’ll find a section about Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the line you have posted above says is that your type has a property called `logInUser`. The property is of type `User`. Therefore if you access that property, you will have an object of type `User` and can work with it as such. If for example your `User` type has a property called `firstName` you could access that property by saying `var userFirstName = logInUser.firstName` for example.

The explanation point (!) means that your `logInUser` variable is an implicitly unwrapped optional. This means that you are saying to the compiler "this variable, although an optional, should ALWAYS be force unwrapped when accessed". Even though the property is an optional, you will not need to use if/let binding or force unwrapping to access it. If you do access the property and it is nil, you will get a runtime crash.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no inheritance in this statement, what's happening is simple:

A model is a representation of real/imaginary things in a bit world, in simple ways.
This means that the model "User" represent the user of the application and contains all the things needed to do this representation.

For example, what an user needs to be uniquely recognized by the system Email/username or both, for example. Obviously, a model can contain anything useful, for example to make an order the model should contain even the address.

Now, what's important is that a model is just a model and this means that you can use that model to literally create users in your system/app.

To write something like

```
   var loginUser: User
```

Maybe, in the case of an iOS app, in a view controller, means that the controller needs to know who is the user who is using the app.

So, the `loginUser` is a variable representing an instance of `User` model, which means that `loginUser` ***is-a*** `User`, not its inheritance.

More technically, in your case if your `User` class (model) contains for example the property `email`, you can access that email  by typing `logInUser.email` and do something like showing it or using it to authentication and so on.

> Notice that I have used the work `class` which is actually a model, while `logInUser` is an object, which is an ***instance*** of a class, that is a concretization of the class. That means that you can have multiple object of the same class representing different users, for example: `var adminUser: User, var customerUser: User, var loggedInUser: User` which are different users with different informations and so they are different instances of the same class.

check this [object programming explanation](https://www.raywenderlich.com/599-object-oriented-programming-in-swift)

2) The exclamation point is a forced unwrap, that means that a user can or cannot exists and it is not needed its initialization in an init because it could be `nil` (but you have to give it a valid value to use it), that stands for "non-existing". Actually, the notation `var someV: User?` says that your variable can contain an `User` type or a `nil` value.

The difference of your notation with `!` from

```
  var logInUser: User?
```

is that when you're using the variable, if you declared it with `!`, you can use it without unwrap it:

```
  func someFunction(){
    var email = logInUser.email
  }
```

But this could fail if you didn't initialized your `logInUser` somewhere.

If you used `?` instead, you need to unwrap it:

```
  func someFunction(){
    var email = logInUser?.email
    // OR 
    var email2 = logInUser!.email
  }
```

The difference in the previous use of `logInUser` is that `logInUser?.email` can return `nil`, while `logInUser!.email` try to force the unwrap and if it fails your app will crash.